# General error: 126 Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_dda_0.MYI'; try to repair it

Tags: magento-community, ce-1.9.2.4, frontend-error

The website I have just made live on Magento has crashed after one day of activity.

I have checked the error log and it begins with the following ...

> a:5:{i:0;s:144:"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 126 Incorrect key file
>   for table '/tmp/#sql_dda_0.MYI';

try to repair it, query was: **DESCRIBE `log_visitor_info`";i:1;s:3547:"#0**

Does anyone know what this means, or can assist me in fixing this issue please?
Thanks

Comment: maybe the disk is full

Answer (score 1):

Go to your Database and select your DB

Click Structure -> select "log_visitor_info"

and select "repair table" from bottom drop-down.